# Conditional Attributes in MVC4 not working?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am trying to adding css class based on condition. But it is not working. even I tried `@classes` too.

```
 @{
    string classes = meetingQuestion.is_mandatory != null && 
                    (bool) meetingQuestion.is_mandatory ? "mandatory" : null;
   }
  <div class="col-md-6">@Html.Label(meetingQuestion.question_text_en, 
                        new { @class = "control-label classes" })</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to *append* the `classes` variable to the string instead of using the name *in* the string:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">@Html.Label(meetingQuestion.question_text_en, 
                    new { @class = "control-label " + classes })</div>
```